# How to parameterize the schema within same target in DBT project

Tags: dbt

I am splitting the model in 4 subfolders, each subfolder having specific sql models.

```
model1 - schema STG_dev
model2 - schema ODS_dev
model3 - schema DWH_dev
model4 - schema FIN_dev
```

I need different schemas per each folder/model and I do not want to write the schema name as hardcoded value in the config() at the beginning of the sql script.

Any idea how can I calculate the schema value as a variable, taking into consideration the model subfolder name?

Comment: You can set a default schema for each model subfolder in `dbt_project.yml`

Answer (score 3):

You can define in the [model configuration](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/model-configs) in **dbt_project.yml** with the `+` syntax.

Example:

```yaml
models:
  project_name:
    STG_dev:
      +schema: STG_dev
    ODS_dev:
      +schema: ODS_dev
    DWH_dev:
      +schema: DWH_dev
    STG_dev:
      +schema: STG_dev
    FIN_dev:
      +schema: FIN_dev
```

Now all models under their corresponding directory will have that schema name applied. For example models under `models/STG_dev` will have `STG_dev` schema.

You can verify by checking `target/manifest.json` file, after running a `dbt compile`.